# Android Studio Cannot resolve symbol "content"

Tags: android, android-layout

Took up doing some app development and I was following this google tutorial:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

In the Display Message section they have a piece of code: `RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);` that works in the tutorial but it doesn't work for me.

I get an error saying, cannot resolve symbol "content". Here is my code:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null)
                    .show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
    layout.addView(textView);
}

}
```

When I click on the suggested fix, there's the option of doing the following:
Create id value resource "content"
Create field "content"
Rename reference.

Here is my content_display_message.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.test.DisplayMessageActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_display_message">

    android:id="@+id/content">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please can you show your `activity_display_message.xml`? check weather RelativeLayout is assigned with id `android:id="@+id/content"`

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a RelativeLayout with `android:id="@+id/content"` in your `activity_display_message.xml` file.

Comment: @TudorLuca Look at the edit. The google tutorial said to put android:id="@+id/content" in the content_display_message.xml. Was I supposed to put it in activity_display_message.xml instead?

Comment: @samz_manu no, it's ok what the tutorial sais. Check my answer, your layout file `content_display_message.xml` has invalid xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content_display_message.xml` file is not valid xml:

```
...
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_display_message">
android:id="@+id/content">
...
```

Remove the `>` from line `tools:showIn="@layout/activity_display_message">`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `activity_display_message.xml` there must be id assigned to layout like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/content">

    <!-- Other layouts -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the recent versions of android studio the dimens.xml is not available by default.

@dimen refers to dimension and it's a file where you define dimensions to use them later from in any layout file.

It's located in `res/values/dimens` , here's what a sample of the file look like:

```
 <resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
  </resources>
```